# Understanding the homomorphism: $(A, +) \cong \mathbb{Z} / p^2 \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

So my professor randomly wrote the following sentence in his lecture:

> If $A$ is a ring with $p^2$ elements, then $(A, +)  \cong \mathbb{Z} / p^2 \mathbb{Z} or \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$.

But he didn't prove it. where could I find a proof?

Comment: You can't. That's not true. There is one more possibility.

Comment: Here, I've edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove this because there are two possibilities: $\mathbb{Z}/(p^2)$, or $\mathbb{Z}/(p) \times \mathbb{Z}/(p)$. This follows from the classification of finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups. You can probably find its proof in many books. One possible resource in the case of finite groups (note that the theorem is more general: it classifies finitely generated groups) is this:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups